# Autodesk Markup positioning is wrong in the screenshot

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

following is my code to generate the screenshot along with the markups

```js
function generateSnapshotWithMarkUp(ncrNo_, luName_, keyRef_, markupsStringData) {
  let screenshot = new Image();
  const mimeType = 'image/png';
  screenshot.onload = async function () {
      const markupCore = await createdViewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
      markupCore.show();
      markupCore.loadMarkups(markupsStringData, "layer1");
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = createdViewer.container.clientWidth;
      canvas.height = createdViewer.container.clientHeight;
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(screenshot, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      markupCore.renderToCanvas(ctx, function () {
          // Convert canvas to Blob, then Blob to ArrayBuffer.
          canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
            CreateAndConnectMediaWithBlob(ncrNo_, luName_, keyRef_, blob);   
            markupCore.leaveEditMode();
            markupCore.hide();
          }, mimeType);
      }, false);
  };
  createdViewer.getScreenShot(createdViewer.container.clientWidth, createdViewer.container.clientHeight, function (blobURL) {
    screenshot.src = blobURL;
  });
}
```

And the original markup is

[image: Original Mark Up]

But for the screenshot I get

[image: screenshot]

This is random but i did notice sometimes when you move the model (or move the view using "Pan") around (specially along with the X axis) this happens.

Is it something wrong when I draw the canvas or something else ??

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [udda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578971/udda)'s answer:

Here's how the markups are kept in sync with the viewer camera:

- Whenever the camera changes, the `MarkupsCore` extension calls its own method called `onCameraChange` to sync its markups' position and scale accordingly
- The `onCameraChange` method calls another method of the extension object called `getSvgViewBox` to compute the "world coordinates" for all four corners of the viewer canvas
- The world coordinates are then used to specify the SVG element's [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute

With that said, the markups should always stay in sync unless the `onCameraChange` method is not called for some reason before you attempt to generate the screenshot. Try adding a break point into the method to see if it gets called as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I might have found out what my code is missing , so I add the following code before loading markups

missing point was the "state"

```js
var viewerStatePersist = markUp_.viewer.getState()
```

and then added it before loading the markups

```js
markup.viewer.restoreState(viewerStatePersist);
```

so my final code would look like this

```js
function generateSnapshotWithMarkUp(ncrNo_, luName_, keyRef_, markupsStringData, viewerStatePersist) {
  let screenshot = new Image();
  const mimeType = 'image/png';
  screenshot.onload = async function () {
      const markupCore = await createdViewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
      markup.viewer.restoreState(viewerStatePersist);
      markupCore.show();
      markupCore.loadMarkups(markupsStringData, "layer1");
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = createdViewer.container.clientWidth;
      canvas.height = createdViewer.container.clientHeight;
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(screenshot, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      markupCore.renderToCanvas(ctx, function () {
          // Convert canvas to Blob, then Blob to ArrayBuffer.
          canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
            CreateAndConnectMediaWithBlob(ncrNo_, luName_, keyRef_, blob);   
            markupCore.leaveEditMode();
            markupCore.hide();
          }, mimeType);
      }, false);
  };
  createdViewer.getScreenShot(createdViewer.container.clientWidth, createdViewer.container.clientHeight, function (blobURL) {
    screenshot.src = blobURL;
  });
}
```

Not sure if it is the real solution but worked for me ...